# Should I use "to" or "of", which one is gramtically correct?

Tags: grammar

I am writing a blog post and the titles are

> Ultimate Guide of Best Mens Hairstyles

or

> Ultimate Guide to Best Mens Hairstyles

I am unsure as which one is grammatically correct, and any help would be appreciated thank you in advance.

Comment: or *for*? Decisions!

Comment: Oh i see, are "of" and "to" both grammatically correct? as from google searches, it seemed most people used "to" after "guide", however if "of" is correct, then i will keep it.

Comment: It's ***to*** for all purposes. (I will provide a detailed answer when I am back, *if* the Q isn't answered by then.) Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think both are grammatically correct.  The usage will be based on what you are trying to convey.

Using to, to me, would mean more of an instructional or a how to type guide.

Using of, to me, would mean more of a list or description of the hairstyles.

Comment: My blog post is both a instructional and a list, i.e its a list of best hairstyles and for each style it provides a tutorial on how to do it, which make it even more confusing, I appreciate your answer.